# Adobe Premiere Elements 10: File > Export is greyed out

Tags: premiere-elements

I have a new install of APE 10 on a Windows 7 64-bit machine.

I am a new user of APE.

I have edited a .MOV file, and now I want to save it in a format compatible with YouTube.

When I go to the File menu, **Export is greyed out**.

What are the requirements before being able to export in Adobe Premiere Elements 10?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Export function was removed a couple of generations ago but it is still in the file menu as its used for a couple of things such as tiles.

All video is output using the "Share" button.

If you want some extra information on this matter here is an answer from Adobe:
http://helpx.adobe.com/premiere-elements/kb/export-option-unavailable-premiere-elements.html

Hope that helps!